# ¿Como manejar el error de tiempo de expiración en Transbank SDK para PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, api

Transbank es una empresa que permite los pagos electrónicos con diferentes entidades y servicios en Chile.

Resulta que ya pasamos todas las pruebas y estamos a punto de pasar a producción pero nos hemos percatado de un error al momento de que llegamos al portal de Webpay y el usuario no hace nada. Tiene un tiempo de alrededor de 5 minutos en el cual, sino sucede nada, redirige a la `redirect_url` que se envía al momento de crear la transacción.

Cuando el usuario llega al portal y "por ABC motivo" no realiza el pago, actúa el tiempo de expiración y vuelve a la aplicación web pero me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He habilitado la ruta mediante el método PUT, pensando que podría ser eso pero el error continua, no podemos dar con la solución. Espero de antemano si alguien tiene más conocimientos al respecto.

Comment: tu ruta de retorno es un metodo post o get, y la api te esta devolviendo la respuesta en un metodo put, basta con crear la ruta con el metodo put para corregir ese error

Comment: Sí, como mencioné, habilite la ruta mediante el método PUT pero sigue arrojando el mismo error. Hasta el momento lo estamos manejando de otra manera, ya que, no estamos permitiendo reembolsos y no nos afecta directamente.

Comment: esa ruta requiere estar logueado? Acuérdate de https://github.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-sdk-php/issues/211. Debe ser lo mismo

Comment: Gracias, claro requería estar logueado, ya encontramos la manera de recibir la petición, gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a los comentarios, la solución era permitir el método PUT en la dirección de redirección solicitada por Transbank. Además, se debe manejar la respuesta en algún controlador según tu aplicación web.